# Please update the PHP tag wiki to reflect releases 5.3.5 and 5.2.17

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tag-wiki

PHP Group has [released 5.3.5 and 5.2.17](http://www.php.net/releases/5_3_5.php), please update the tag wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Updated](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info)